# empty path name is not legal (vb.net 2005 ,access 2000,)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

[Error] empty path name is not legal
         The problem is I cannot insert image to Access database. Which line is error. Thanks In advance who helping me

Regards,
Fizul

```
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim fsreader As New IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName,IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Dim breader As New IO.BinaryReader(fsreader)

    Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
    breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
    fsreader.Close()

    cnn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source = |datadirectory|\db1.accdb;"
    cnn.Open()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "insert into Table1 Values(" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & imgbuffer.Length & "')"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    cnn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these first two lines:

```
Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
Dim fsreader As New IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName,IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

You created an instance of OpenFileDialog, but you never called it's ShowDialog method so the FileName property is Nothing.  You need something like this:

```
Using OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fsreader As New IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName,IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        'remaining of code here
    End If
End Using
```

The `Using` statement makes sure that the dialog is disposed correctly.